# Hide menu sidebar when clicking outside the bar or the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a menu like the semantic UI but I only achieved to click the menu button and open the menu and vice versa. I use toggle class to show the sidebar but I dont know if this way is completely right:

```
<div class="menu-button" id="menu-button"></div>

$('#menu-button').click(function(event) {
     $('#hide-menu').toggleClass('show-menu');
});

.hide-menu {
    background-color:#336ca6;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(300px,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(300px,0,0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(300px,0,0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(300px,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(300px,0,0);      
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.show-menu {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 }
```

[I've tried the event propagation](http://jsfiddle.net/ex8ddv5q/) but I can't manage to make it play.

Comment: Show the whole code or a JSfiddle

Comment: Where is `hide-menu` and `show-menu`?

Comment: Would you show a demo please?

Comment: Try the solution of this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65236502/7688047

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Edit your js code to following

```
$('#menu-button').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#hide-menu').toggleClass('show-menu');
});

$('#hide-menu').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('body,html').click(function(e){
   $('#hide-menu').removeClass('show-menu');
});
```

Hope this will work.

Here is fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/ex8ddv5q/1/

Answer (score 8):

For a different take on it check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLaLdLjq/)

```
$('#menu-button').click(function (evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    $('#hide-menu').toggleClass('show-menu');
});


$('body,html').click(function (e) {

    var container = $("#hide-menu");

    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        container.removeClass('show-menu');

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In case somebody comes here and is using Angular instead of JQuery, we got this to work with something similar to the above like this:

```
public toggleSideNav() {
    this.showSideNav = !this.showSideNav;
    console.log('show side nav', this.showSideNav);
    event.stopPropagation();
}

public hideSideNav() {
    this.showSideNav = false;
    console.log('hide side nav');
}
```

And this in the template:

```
<app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
<div class="main-body" (click)="applicationService.hideSideNav()">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose if your sidebar width is 270px,check the mouse click coordinate.If it's greater give its style left attribute as -270px;

```
function handleMousePos(event) {
      var mouseClickWidth = event.clientX;
      if(mouseClickWidth>=270){
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.left='-270px'
           }
}

document.addEventListener("click", handleMousePos);
```

Here is my sample:https://codepen.io/johncy/pen/oMyzZr

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').click(function(){
     $('#hide-menu').removeClass('show-menu');
});
```

Comment: Because your body height = button height