# how to hide dropdown menu when click out in any place of the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the below code for dropdown menu, this code I use to put items in dropdown list if menu bar width is not enough to display all items depend on the screen width.
all working fine but I want when click out to hide the dropdown menu
I tried .**mouseup** but didnt work
I hope you can help me
all working fine but I want when click out to hide the dropdown menu
I tried .**mouseup** but didnt work
the code is very big

```
   <script>
    var $nav = $('.greedy-nav');
    var $btn = $('.greedy-nav button');
     var $vlinks = $('.greedy-nav .visible-links');
    var $hlinks = $('.greedy-nav .hidden-links');
    var breaks = [];
    function updateNav() {
    var availableSpace = $btn.hasClass('hidden') ? $nav.width() : $nav.width() - 
    $btn.width() - 30;
    if($vlinks.width() > availableSpace) {
    breaks.push($vlinks.width());
    $vlinks.children().last().prependTo($hlinks);
    if($btn.hasClass('hidden')) {
    $btn.removeClass('hidden');
 }
  } else {
  if(availableSpace > breaks[breaks.length-1]) {
  $hlinks.children().first().appendTo($vlinks);
  breaks.pop();
  }
 if(breaks.length < 1) {
  $btn.addClass('hidden');
  $hlinks.addClass('hidden');
 }
 }
 $btn.attr("count", breaks.length);
 if($vlinks.width() > availableSpace) {
 updateNav();
}
}
 $(window).resize(function() {
  updateNav();
  });

 $btn.on('click', function() {
 $hlinks.toggleClass("hidden");
  });
  updateNav();
 </script>
```

**HTML**

```
 <div id="shouldPin">
 <div class="ItemListForMenu_shouldPin" id="CategoriesList">
<div class="MenuCategoriesList_categoriesSection">
<nav class='greedy-nav'>
<button id="mybtn">More</button>
<ul id="mainNav" class='visible-links'>
<li><a href='' class="MainCategory">Appetizers</a></li>
<li><a href='' class="MainCategory">Soups</a></li>
<li><a href='' class="MainCategory">Salads</a></li>
<li><a href='' class="MainCategory">Sashimi or Sushi</a></li>
 <li><a href='' class="MainCategory">Appetizers</a></li>
<li><a href='' class="MainCategory">Soups</a></li>
<li><a href='' class="MainCategory">Salads</a></li>
<li><a href='' class="MainCategory">Sashimi or Sushi</a></li>
<li><a href='' class="MainCategory">Appetizers</a></li>
<li><a href='' class="MainCategory">Soups</a></li>
<li><a href='' class="MainCategory">Salads</a></li>
<li><a href='' class="MainCategory">Sashimi or Sushi</a></li>
<li><a href='' class="MainCategory">Appetizers</a></li>
<li><a href='' class="MainCategory">Soups</a></li>
<li><a href='' class="MainCategory">Salads</a></li>
<li><a href='' class="MainCategory">Sashimi or Sushi</a></li>
 </ul>
    <ul id="menu_dropdown" class='hidden-links hidden'></ul>
   </nav>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Check it one out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29960942/hide-menu-sidebar-when-clicking-outside-the-bar-or-the-button

Comment: What is the variable name for the dropdown element? Is it `$btn`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`$.contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.contains/) to determine if an element is inside of another element. You need to create a click handler on the entire document and check if the click `target` is inside the dropdown or not:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    const dropdown = $('.dropdown');
    if(!$.contains(dropdown, e.target) {
        // Close dropdown
        $(dropdown).toggleClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

And to keep your app performant, you only want to add the click event to the `document` when the **dropdown is open** and remove the click event from `document` when the dropdown is closed.

**EDIT:** Here is a working snippet demonstrating my suggestion. You first check if the dropdown is already hidden and then check to see if the user clicked a link in the dropdown. If neither of those are true, then it will hide the second dropdown. Clicking outside of the menu will close the second dropdown:

```js
var $nav = $('.greedy-nav');
var $btn = $('.greedy-nav button');
var $vlinks = $('.greedy-nav .visible-links');
var $hlinks = $('.greedy-nav .hidden-links');
var breaks = [];

function updateNav() {
  var availableSpace = $btn.hasClass('hidden') ? $nav.width() : $nav.width() -
    $btn.width() - 30;
  if ($vlinks.width() > availableSpace) {
    breaks.push($vlinks.width());
    $vlinks.children().last().prependTo($hlinks);
    if ($btn.hasClass('hidden')) {
      $btn.removeClass('hidden');
    }
  } else {
    if (availableSpace > breaks[breaks.length - 1]) {
      $hlinks.children().first().appendTo($vlinks);
      breaks.pop();
    }
    if (breaks.length < 1) {
      $btn.addClass('hidden');
      $hlinks.addClass('hidden');
    }
  }
  $btn.attr("count", breaks.length);
  if ($vlinks.width() > availableSpace) {
    //updateNav();
  }
}
$(window).resize(function() {
  //updateNav();
});

$btn.on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $hlinks.toggleClass("hidden");
});

updateNav();

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  // Check if the dropdown is already hidden
  // Check if the clicked target exists in the hidden dropdown
  // Check if the clicked target exists in the visible dropdown
  // If none are true, then hide the dropdown
  if (!$($hlinks).hasClass('hidden') &&
    !$.contains($hlinks[0], e.target) &&
    !$.contains($vlinks[0], e.target)) {
    $($hlinks).addClass('hidden');
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.visible-links {
  background: #ededed;
}

.hidden-links {
  background: #222;
}

.hidden-links a {
  color: #FFF;
}

#shouldPin {
  padding-bottom: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="shouldPin">
  <div class="ItemListForMenu_shouldPin" id="CategoriesList">
    <div class="MenuCategoriesList_categoriesSection">
      <nav class='greedy-nav'>
        <button id="mybtn">More</button>
        <ul id="mainNav" class='visible-links'>
          <li>Appetizers</li>
          <li><a href='' class="MainCategory">Soups</a></li>
          <li><a href='' class="MainCategory">Salads</a></li>
          <li><a href='' class="MainCategory">Sashimi or Sushi</a></li>
          <li><a href='' class="MainCategory">Appetizers</a></li>
          <li><a href='' class="MainCategory">Soups</a></li>
          <li><a href='' class="MainCategory">Salads</a></li>
          <li><a href='' class="MainCategory">Sashimi or Sushi</a></li>
          <li><a href='' class="MainCategory">Appetizers</a></li>
          <li><a href='' class="MainCategory">Soups</a></li>
          <li><a href='' class="MainCategory">Salads</a></li>
          <li><a href='' class="MainCategory">Sashimi or Sushi</a></li>
          <li><a href='' class="MainCategory">Appetizers</a></li>
          <li><a href='' class="MainCategory">Soups</a></li>
          <li><a href='' class="MainCategory">Salads</a></li>
          <li><a href='' class="MainCategory">Sashimi or Sushi</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="menu_dropdown" class='hidden-links hidden'></ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your code doesnt work, I tried this code the problem now is when click out it shows and hide the dropdownmenu but if clicked on the more button the dropdown doesnt appear

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).mouseup(function(e)  {
    const dropdown = $('.hidden-links');
    if(!$.contains(dropdown, e.target)) {
        // Close dropdown
         $(dropdown).toggleClass('hidden');
     
    }
});
</script>

Comment: Yeah this is only an example. You would need to post more code or a snippet for me to give you an exact answer. This should help you understand **how** to accomplish it, but you'll need to tweak it meet your exact needs. Please post your html code and css and I can take another look. Also, use the `click` event, not `mouseup` on `document`.

Comment: hope you can help me also in making menu to be slide smoothly

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zkkk7zgk0tt1f04/myfile.zip?dl=0

Comment: Posting your entire project isn't going to help me. I need you to only post the relevant code for the dropdown or make a small runnable example. There is too much code to go through and try to figure out what's going on.

Comment: All I can Add just the HTML you know the role they dont accept to add code while text is little, so now you have the html and BTW the css is not that important

Comment: @AshMax Updated answer with snippet