# how to hide sidebar when clicking outside of sidebar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a sidebar that looks like this:

[image]

Clicking the arrow will collapse the sidebar again. However, I want to auto close the sidebar if I click outside of the sidebar. Would that be possible?

This is my script for toggling the sidebar:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#sidebar").mCustomScrollbar({
                theme: "minimal"
            });

            $('#dismiss, .overlay').on('click', function() {
                $('#sidebar').removeClass('active');
                $('.overlay').removeClass('active');
            });

            $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function() {
                $('#sidebar').addClass('active');
                $('.overlay').addClass('active');
                $('.collapse.in').toggleClass('in');
                $('a[aria-expanded=true]').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
            });
        });



    </script>
```

The toggler icon (hamburger) that expands the sidebar:

```
 <div class="col-4 my-auto text-left p-1">
                        <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn">
                            <i class="fa fa-bars navigation-icon"></i>
                        </button>
```

Some CSS:

```
#sidebar {
    width: 250px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: -250px;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 999;
    background: #fbcc34;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#sidebar.active {
    left: 0;
}

#dismiss {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #000000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#dismiss:hover {
    background: #fff;
    color: #7386d5;
}

.overlay {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    z-index: 998;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.overlay.active {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #000000;
}
```

So when I click anywhere outside the sidebar, it should close the sidebar automatically. Do I have to create a separate function to achieve this?

Comment: Try the solution of this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65236502/7688047

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with code below:

```js
$('body').click(function(event){
   if($(event.target).attr('id') !== "sidebar" && $(event.target).attr('id') !== "sidebarCollapse") {
     $('#sidebar').removeClass('active');
     $('.overlay').removeClass('active');
   }
});
```

Comment: it does not work. i can't even toggle the sidebar now

Comment: Please put this code: $('body').click(function(event){console.log($(event.target).attr('id'))}
Then click in your sidebar and check the console, what message you get?

Comment: And the sidebar not closing when you clicking outside of it?

Comment: Do I have to comment out my previous code? Pls post the full code so i can understand. Because I cannot even toggle my sidebar open

Comment: I edited my answer again, you can copy the whole js script now. Btw, I'm sure that method is working because I using it myself for my website and it works fine. Just If I knew about your HTML structures, I could help you more.

Comment: Yea your logic is correct but no idea why it won't remove it

Comment: I think I know why, because when I tried to click on the hamburger icon, it won't expand the sidebar as it is part of `body` so it closes.

Comment: Good for you! Tbh I don't have enough source codes from you so I can't helping more. But I'm sure you can achive this with that code I posted. Just try to debug with your browser console and edit that code to works fine with your website.

Comment: Yeap it works. I tried to replace `body` with `footer` and it works. You helped me a lot so I will mark your answer. The thing is my HTML structure is divided into 3 sections. Navigation bar (where the toggler icon is), content, and footer. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Oh great! Thanks a lot.

Comment: One thing thought, since I have separate files, how do I include all of them in one? Like $('body','footer','my own id').click(function(event)? So it could detect all the changes

Comment: First of all, I think your HTML structure is not true. Because the footer must be inside the body. 

I think you can do that with on() function, something like this:
$("body").on('click', 'footer, #YourOwnId', function (event) {        
    console.log('clicked');           
});

Comment: I don't remember it works too or not:

$("#YourOwnId, .YourOwnClass").click(function(e) {
console.log('clicked')
}